# Modifying the HTML of a page before it is sent to the client

Tags: asp.net, html

I need to catch the HTML of a ASP.NET just before it is being sent to the client in order to do last minute string manipulations on it, and then send the modified version to the client.

e.g.

The Page is loaded
Every control has been rendered correctly
The Full html of the page is ready to be transferred back to the client

Is there a way to that in ASP.NET?

Comment: Dude, don't downvote everyone who doesn't tell you exactly what you want to hear in their response. It's not a good way to encourage more people to help you.  I don't think I've ever seen so many people downvoted in the same question.

Comment: He may not be the one that did it...Might've been him, but who knows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can override the Render method of your page. Then call the base implementation and supply your HtmlTextWriter object. Here is an example

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    StringWriter output = new StringWriter();
    base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(output));
    //This is the rendered HTML of your page. Feel free to manipulate it.
    string outputAsString = output.ToString();

    writer.Write(outputAsString);
}
```

Comment: Just discovered that using your approach breaks ASP.NET Ajax when using an `UpdatePanel` The JavaScript error is similar to "[The message received from the server could not be parsed](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx)".

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [HTTPModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttpmodule.aspx) to change the html. Here is a [sample](http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/03/03/web-page-optmisation-using-httpmodule.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Using the [answer of Atanas Korchev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288740/107625) for some days, I discovered that I get JavaScript errors similar to:

> "The message received from the server could not be parsed"

When using this in conjunction with an ASP.NET Ajax [`UpdatePanel` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx). [The reason is described in this blog post](http://weblogs.asp.net/leftslipper/archive/2007/02/26/sys-webforms-pagerequestmanagerparsererrorexception-what-it-is-and-how-to-avoid-it.aspx).

Basically the `UpdatePanel` seems to be critical about the exact length of the rendered string being constant. I.e. if you change the string and *keep* the length, it succeeds, if you change the text so that the string length changes, the above JavaScript error occurs.

My not-perfect-but-working solution was to assume the `UpdatePanel` always does a POST and filter that away:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (IsPostBack || IsCallback)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
    }
    else
    {
        using (var output = new StringWriter())
        {
            base.Render(new HtmlTextWriter(output));

            var outputAsString = output.ToString();
            outputAsString = doSomeManipulation(outputAsString);

            writer.Write(outputAsString);
        }
    }
}
```

This works in my scenario but has some drawbacks that may not work for your scenario:

- Upon postbacks, no strings are changed.
- The string that the user sees therefore is the unmanipulated one
- The `UpdatePanel` may fire for NON-postbacks, too.

Still, I hope this helps others who discover a similar issue. Also, [see this article discussing `UpdatePanel` and `Page.Render` in more details](http://7daysageek.blogspot.de/2009/03/aspnet-updatepanel-and-overriding.html).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the sequence of events in the ASP.NET page's lifecycle.  [Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx) one page that lists the events.  It's possible you could find an event to handle that's late enough in the page's lifecycle to make your changes, but still get those changes rendered.

If not, you could always write an HttpModule that processes the HTTP response after the page itself has finished rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously it will be much more efficient if you can coax the desired markup out of ASP.Net in the first place.

With that in mind, have you considered using [Control Adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter.aspx)?  They will allow you to over-ride how each of your controls render in the first place, rather than having to modify the string later.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think there is a specific event from the page that you can hook into; here is the ASP.Net lifecycle: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

You may want to consider hooking into the prerender event to 'adjust' the values of the controls, or perform some client side edits/callbacks.