# How to access the hyperlink in a BulletedList in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, bulletedlist

If I have a BulletedList web control set to have a displaymode="hyperlink", is there a way to programatically access the hyperlink server-side?  The closest I can get to it is the parent li tag, but that is not what i need.  I need to apply a css class to the link, and if I do it client-side, I see that tiny little flicker between before the class was applied and after it was applied.

Ideas?

**Update:**

```
<asp:BulletedList ID="List1" runat="server" DisplayMode="HyperLink">
<asp:ListItem Value="http://www.google.com">Go to Google</asp:ListItem>
</asp:BulletedList>


List1.Items[0].Attributes.Add("class", "some_basic_class"); //this applies to the <li> tag
```

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just use the CSS selector to select anchor tag inside the list item for which you want to apply the class? So apply the class to the `<li>` tag, and then use the css selector to modify the anchor tag inside of it.

```
.selected-li-class a { font-color: red; }
```

Comment: I can't make alterations to the stylesheet in question.  I just need to know if I can access the hyperlink.

Comment: Via the bulletedlist, I don't believe so. If you are really adamant about adding the class directly to the hyperlink, you could modify the html before it is rendered, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/278163/asp-net-modifing-the-html-of-a-page-before-it-is-sent-to-the-client